# Custom UITableViewCell is blank (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am attempting to setup a custom UITableViewCell in Swift. I have created the XIB file and swift file as well. However, when I run the app the cells are not populated with my custom cell, but rather a completely blank cell.

**I have registered my cell with:**

```
self.myTableView.registerClass(customCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

**I have also setup the following:**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return 3
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! customCell
   cell.descriptionLabel.text = "test"
   return cell
}
```

In addition, I have setup a link to a UILabel in the custom cell. When I try to update it the app crashes. The line is `cell.descriptionLabel.text = "test"` as shown above.

Comment: Did you set the class of your xib to your custom cell class under the identity inspector?

Comment: Have you added the number of sections in row?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of register the `UITableViewCell` class, you must register the nib, for example:

```
self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

The `nibName` is the name of the XIB file but without the `.xib` extension.